# Git merge shows local changes while status doesn't reflect that

Tags: git, git-merge

Git merge gives the error:

> Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge

On doing `git status` there are no files to be committed.

Comment: I suspect this: your current working tree has files that are ignored and untracked; the branch being merged has these files tracked so git cannot merge. Backup the files and remove them; conclude merge and then decide if you want to restore the files from backup.

Comment: I tried doing that. Now there are no untracked files shown on doing `git status`. But I am getting the same error.

Comment: Instead of merging branch into master I was able to merge master into the branch. Then, I checked out back to master and tried merging and it worked! I still have no idea about the reason behind the issue.